# AngularJS suggestion text in a textbox does not clear after selection is made

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a textbox with suggestion text using AngularJS. I have a textbox on my page and wheat I want is whenever user starts typing something in, some suggestions to pop-up where the user can select an option that will get written into a textbox.
The list of values comes from a database. 
I got that part working, but one thing is still giving me problems - once the user starts typing, the list comes up and allows the user to select a value. But once the value is selected in the list and is populated into the textbox, the list of possible values still is shown. Is there a way to hide it without clearing the value in the textbox?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="TextApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="BaseCtrl.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="BaseController">
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 50%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" ng-model="fnamequery">
        <p id="pfname" ng-repeat="fname in fnames | filter:fnamequery" ng-hide="fnamequery==''"><a ng-href="" ng-click="GetSuggestion(fname)">{{fname}}</a></p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my controller is here:

```
angular.module('TextApp', []).controller('BaseController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.fnames = [];
$scope.fnamequery = '';

 $http.get('http://localhost:49358/api/myClasses/GetAllNames/').
    then(function (response) {
        $scope.fnames = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
        //print error to console.
        console.log(error);
    });


    $scope.GetSuggestion = function (strname) {
        $scope.fnamequery = strname;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
<body ng-controller="BaseController">
<div class="input-group" style="width: 50%;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" ng-model="fnamequery" ng-change="fnamePicked = false;">
    <p id="pfname" ng-repeat="fname in fnames | filter:fnamequery" ng-hide="fnamequery=='' || fnamePicked"><a ng-href="" ng-click="GetSuggestion(fname)">{{fname}}</a></p>

</div>
```

```
 angular.module('TextApp', []).controller('BaseController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.fnames = [];
$scope.fnamequery = '';
$scope.fnamePicked = false;

 $http.get('http://localhost:49358/api/myClasses/GetAllNames/').
    then(function (response) {
        $scope.fnames = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
        //print error to console.
        console.log(error);
    });

    $scope.GetSuggestion = function (strname) {
        $scope.fnamequery = strname;
            $scope.fnamePicked = true;
    }
});
```

EDIT:
any reason you cant use one of the MANY autocompletes that already exist for angularjs?

Comment: cDecker32, I thought about it but first wanted to give it a try myself

Comment: Fair enough, the general rule of thumb with angularJS is to try and do ALL DOM manipulation with the built in Angular directives. Stuff can get super funky when you start trying to put jQuery in there.

Comment: I am thinking of trying out angular material auto-complete

Comment: I've recently started messing around with it and its quite nice.